# How is Svelte using the 'this' keyword in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, this, svelte

I'm going through the tutorial for Svelte and came upon this example, and am confused as to how this is working. (I cut out some other code not relevant to question, full example here: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tick)

```
<script>
   async function handleKeydown(event) {
     const { selectionStart, selectionEnd, value } = this;

     await tick();
     this.selectionStart = selectionStart;
     this.selectionEnd = selectionEnd;
   }
</script>

<textarea value={text} on:keydown={handleKeydown}></textarea>
```

Could someone please explain the logic of how 'this' is being used here?  I don't understand how it knows to reference the value within the textarea. Does it have something to do with the function being called by the textarea and creating a context within the function referencing the textarea element?

And also why something like the code below does not work? (console log's undefined)

```
function logger(event) {
 console.log(event.value)
}
```

Comment: About your final paragraph? How do you call `logger`?

Comment: Could you provide feed-back?

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you this makes a lot of sense! Appreciate you taking the time to answer!

Comment: Also regarding the logger function, I was calling it the same way as handleKeydown above, with on:keydown. But i was getting 'undefined' as the console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` is provided by the DOM.

Form MDN's article on [DOM onevent handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handlers_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value):

> When the event handler is invoked, the `this` keyword inside the handler is set to the DOM element on which the handler is registered.

svelte is a framework that builds on top of the DOM, but essentially `on:keydown={handleKeydown}` translates to a DOM event handler binding that has the above quoted property.